# php multi thread variable scope share issue

Tags: php, multithreading, variables, object, pecl

I am make an multi thread cli app with php , but got some problem with the variable sharing between the threads

here is my code:

```
<?php
class testThread extends Thread{
    public function run(){
        wrapper::hello();
    }
}

class wrapper{
    public static $test0;
    public static $test1;
    public static function create(){
        self::$test0 = 'a string';
        self::$test1 = new DateTime();

        echo '#main thread echo start' . "\n";
        var_dump(self::$test0);
        var_dump(self::$test1);
        echo '#main thread echo end' . "\n\n";
        //echo '#---------------------------' . "\n\n";

        $test = new testThread();
        $test->start();
    }

    public static function hello(){
        echo '#sub thread echo start' . "\n\n";
        var_dump(self::$test0);
        var_dump(self::$test1);
        echo '#sub thread echo end' . "\n";
    }
}

wrapper::create();
?>
```

and the result

```
#main thread echo start
string(8) "a string"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-10-14 12:36:17"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(11) "Asia/Taipei"
}
#main thread echo end

#sub thread echo start

string(8) "a string"
NULL
#sub thread echo end
```

in this result , you can see the static String variable can get the value from the sub Thread ,  but the DateTime object is not!

my php version is

> PHP 5.5.4 (cli) (built: Oct  9 2013 11:27:32) (DEBUG) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2013 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013
>   Zend Technologies

If you have any comment please leave it here , It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks.

--------update-----------

here is my phpinfo

```
php test.php | grep "Confi"
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--enable-sockets' '--enable-debug' '--enable-maintainer-zts' '--enable-pthreads'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

**From the Introduction in the PHP manual:**

> Static Members: When a new context is created ( Thread or Worker ),
>   only the simple members of static classes are copied, no resources or
>   objects are copied into the threading context from static class
>   members. This allows them to function as a kind of thread local
>   storage. For example, upon starting the context, a class whose static
>   members include connection information for a database server, and the
>   connection itself, will only have the simple connection information
>   copied, not the connection. Allowing the new context to initiate a
>   connection in the same way as the context that created it, storing the
>   connection in the same place without affecting the original context.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Comment: Thanks for this answer, so there is no possible to share the object between thread? the another way I only think is write the variable to a tmp file to use...but in my case I want to trigger something when the child thread done in the main thread

Comment: This only applies to statics, try reading through examples on github: http://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads, they cover a wide range of topics and should get anyone going ...

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements for php thread:**

pthreads requires a build of PHP with ZTS enabled ( --enable-maintainer-zts or --enable-zts on Windows )

make sure the PECL extensions for php thread is also installed.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have make this configure while php compile , here is my phpinfo()
php test.php | grep "Confi"
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--enable-sockets' '--enable-debug' '--enable-maintainer-zts' '--enable-pthreads'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Configuration